# What is the integrator used in PhysX?

Tags: physx

What type of integrator is used in the PhysX engine? Euler? Runge-Kutta?

I tried to look through the comments in the SDK header and source files. But, could not find any information about this.

Answer (score 4):

From my research, it uses a [Symplectic integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator). I found this in [a paper](http://www.adrianboeing.com/pal/papers/p281-boeing.pdf) comparing various physics simulation systems.